# State transition not persisited in database in integration test using Capybara on a Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, integration-testing

I am using `state_machine` gem -- https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

In my TEST ENVIRONMENT WITH CAPYBARA I am executing

```
order.good_data!
```

`good_data` in an event defined in my state machine.

```
state_machine :initial => :new, :use_transactions => false do

  event :good_data do
    transition [:new] => :sane
  end

end
```

When I check the order in my db it is still in `new` state.

It is working properly in my production and development environments.

Comment: Can you post here/update the question with the code that you are using to test #good_data?

Comment: capybara requires not using transactions in specs.
provide your spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

Use the `database_cleaner` to perform the cleanup. Capybara is using a different thread so your transactions are being executed in a separate thread.

Comment: should that be database_cleaner?

Comment: i don't get how this helps